# How can I convert a string of binary numbers into characters in C (each character has to have a nibble)?

Tags: c, binary, type-conversion, character, ascii

I already looked for useful functions that I can use to convert my string of binary numbers into a string of ASCII characters. I tried converting the string using these C++ libraries

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
```

But my programming environment (CVI from national instruments) does not have them.
I would be glad if someone has an example of a converting function!
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Those aren't "libraries".

Comment: Get the nibbles out with boolean algebra, (bitmask, shifts), and use them to index a literal array "0123456789ABCDEF".

Comment: The headers you mentioned are for C++, but you have tagged your question C.  Which language are you working in?  Also, you'll need to be more clear about what you mean by "string of binary numbers".

Comment: @ScottHunter Header files? I thought they re called libary files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very vague, and no actual attempt is shown which makes it even harder to figure out what you mean.

Perhaps something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hexprint(char *out, const void *in, size_t length)
{
  const static char hexdigits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
  const unsigned char *bin = in;
  while (length--) {
    const unsigned char here = *bin++;
    *out++ = hexdigits[here >> 4];
    *out++ = hexdigits[here & 15];
  }
  *out = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char buf[32], data[] = {0xde, 0xad, 0xf0, 0x0d, 0xba, 0xbe };
    hexprint(buf, data, sizeof data);
    printf("Got '%s'\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints `Got 'deadf00dbabe'`. Note that the output buffer is silently assumed to be Big Enough(TM), be careful.